# Mysql change ft_max_word_len bug

Tags: windows, mysql, indexing, full-text-search

So, I have MySQL installed on my machine, and I need to change the `ft_max_word_len`, the maximum word length that MySQL will index. However, when I set it up via the tools provided, and query it, it still lists it as a max of 84 (I need 128+). When I try and use the command line, I get the following:

```
C:\>mysqld --ft_max_word_len=128
111210 23:55:46 [Warning] option 'ft_max_word_len': unsigned value 256 adjusted to 84
111210 23:55:46 [Warning] option 'ft_max_word_len': unsigned value 128 adjusted to 84
```

It should be noted, I tried to change it to 256 in the GUI tools, so that may be where that value is coming from. But why would I get both, and why can I not adjust this value?

Of note, I am on Windows 7, and MySQL 5.1.41 for 64bit.

**Update:** From @thinice's comment, this leads me to believe that this is a bug in MySQL (and from the sounds of it an [mostly](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,369029) undocumented one, which I will need to change). So maybe my question is, would anyone have any inkling of how to change that value?

Comment: Doesn't change using my.cnf in CentOS on 5.5.18 either - there's little to no documentation on it and no bugs (from my search) - maybe report it as one?

Comment: This is indeed poorly documented. The issue is that max value varies on different OS/bit versions of MySQL.  I am not so sure it is a bug in later version as much as poorly documented. Have you tested MySQL 5.5?

Comment: I figured out the problem without needing to increase the `ft_max_word_len`, but I will test later versions at some point and see if that works. In the meantime, it has been filed as a MySQL bug at http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=63718

Comment: It's a common question, since on a lot of versions default max value cannot be increased. It only changes when you set a smaller value. :/

Comment: I get the same output on Windows 7 x64 and mysql 5.5.24 x64.

Comment: I remember choosing a different Full-Text search add-on in a prototyping program a few years ago. I know it's not helpful, but from memory there was a limitation such as this to the default Full-Text engine. Perhaps 84 is also the max_value that is settable, and the option exists to make it smaller/more efficient?

Comment: You can browse sources to find that value (I think it's hardcoded) and change.

Answer (score 1):

The value of 84 for `HA_FT_MAXCHARLEN` is defined as a third of `HA_FT_MAXBYTELEN` (which is 254). This is defined in `include/ft_global.h` and changing it will mean recompiling MySQL - it is not a run-time variable. The reason it's a third is because in many character sets one character is not equal to one byte.

If you were to change `HA_FT_MAXBYTELEN` and recompile the tests will fail, so you're moving into unsupported-land, though your specific application may work.